# what is Pytorch's add_module()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I stumbled upon the method `add_module()` in a Pytorch model.

[The doc](http://model%20=%20Sequential()%20model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,%20kernel_size=3,%20activation=%27relu%27,%20input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))%20model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,%20kernel_size=3,%20activation=%27relu%27))%20model.add(Dropout(0.5))%20model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))%20model.add(Flatten())%20model.add(Dense(100,%20activation=%27relu%27))%20model.add(Dense(n_outputs,%20activation=%27softmax%27))%20model.compile(loss=%27categorical_crossentropy%27,%20optimizer=%27adam%27,%20metrics=%5B%27accuracy%27%5D)) only states

> Adds a child module to the current module.
>
> The module can be accessed as an attribute using the given name.

I don't understand what "adding a child module" means.

How is it different from just setting a pointer to the other module using `self._other module = other_module`?

What are the nuances?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-to-use-add-module-function/10534

In general, you won’t need to call `add_module`. One potential use case is the following:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
        modules = [...]  # some list of modules
        for module in modules:
            self.add_module(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`nn.Module`s have a hierarchy of child modules that you can access via [methods](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.children) like `module.named_children()` or `module.children()`.

As mentioned in the forum post above, doing `self._other module = other_module` will type check `other_module`, see it's an `nn.Module`, and also add it to the child list, so `add_module` isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a module as an attribute works fine, as you say.  But it can be a bit difficult to do at runtime if you don't know how many modules you have in advance, and you have to construct names programmatically.  In such a case, `add_module()` is a very convenient way to do this.  I've just written a short blog post showing this in action:
https://blog.d-and-j.net/deep-learning/2021/04/23/pytorch-add_module.html